# Cannot resolve symbol " in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I created a fragment by blank Activity with fragment but  I keep getting error that

> CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL " .  yes that double esc char is not resolved.
>   Which leads to a further error in my java file while adding fragment.

Xml Code is this. fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity$DetailFragment"
    >

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detail_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And class file is--

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

THe Error I get is while building Gradle is

> Error:(22, 21) error: no suitable method found for
>   add(int,DetailFragment)  method
>   FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable (argument
>   mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment) method
>   FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable (argument
>   mismatch; DetailFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)

Comment: Hello, you're sure '</ RelativeLayout>' have closed

Comment: Yes That is closed.. I think there is no code error in xml.

Comment: Please also write the code fragment .